# convert rgb images to ycbcr in using for loop gives an TypeError

Tags: numpy, for-loop, opencv, python

I want to access images in my directory and convert them from RGB to YCbCr using a for loop. I am not good at programming and doing what I can.
I have this code below:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2, os
from glob import glob

path= 'the_path_to_the_images'

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    ycbcr = cv2.cvtColor(filename, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCrCb)
    cv2.imwrite( filename, ycbcr)
```

This throws an error:

```
TypeError: src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
```

I have searched some ways to solve it but I couldn't.
How should I fix this?

OR, could anyone please share an alternative way to accomplish my goal here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make the color conversion you need to provide a numpy array or a scalar to `cvtColor` method. So in your case, you first need to read image in your path using `cv2.imread(filename)` and then do the conversion.

A complete solution would be

```
path= 'the_path_to_the_images'

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    image = cv2.imread(filename)
    ycbcr = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCrCb)
    cv2.imwrite( filename, ycbcr)
```